# How to import xlsx to mongodb after parsing it?

Tags: javascript, mongodb, meteor

I have learned the code from sheetJS and I can upload xlsx and show it in JSON format in Meteor way.

[image]

Here is the main.js in client side.

```
import { Template } from 'meteor/templating';
import { ReactiveVar } from 'meteor/reactive-var';

import './main.html';

import { Contacts } from '../imports/api/contacts.js';

const XLSX = require('xlsx');

Template.read.events({
    'change input' (evt, instance) {
        /* "Browser file upload form element" from SheetJS README */
        const file = evt.currentTarget.files[0];
        const reader = new FileReader();
        reader.onload = function(e) {
            const data = e.target.result;
            const name = file.name;
            /* Meteor magic */
            Meteor.call('upload', data, name, function(err, wb) {
                if(err) console.error(err);
                else {
                    /* do something here -- this just dumps an array of arrays to console */
                    console.log(XLSX.utils.sheet_to_json(wb.Sheets[wb.SheetNames[0]], {header:1}));
                    document.getElementById('out').innerText = JSON.stringify(to_json(wb), 2, 2);
                }
            });
        };
        reader.readAsBinaryString(file);
    },
});

function to_json(workbook) {
    var result = {};
    workbook.SheetNames.forEach(function(sheetName) {
        var roa = XLSX.utils.sheet_to_row_object_array(workbook.Sheets[sheetName]);
        if(roa.length > 0){
            result[sheetName] = roa;
        }
    });
    return result;
}
```

The following code that I have tried to insert data to MongoDB.

```
import { Meteor } from 'meteor/meteor';
import { Mongo } from 'meteor/mongo';

export const Contacts = new Mongo.Collection('contacts');

const XLSX = require('xlsx');

Meteor.methods({
    'upload'(bstr, name) {
        /* read the data and return the workbook object to the frontend */
        return XLSX.read(bstr, {type:'binary'});
        for (let i=0; i<bstr.length;i++){
            let item = bstr[i];
            Contacts.insert(bstr[i]);
        }
    },
});
```

Could anybody please help me to import this JSON to mongodb?

I have change contacts.js as Neil suggest:

```
import { Meteor } from 'meteor/meteor';
import { Mongo } from 'meteor/mongo';

export const Contacts = new Mongo.Collection('contacts');

const XLSX = require('xlsx');

Meteor.methods({
    'upload'(bstr, name) {
        /* read the data and return the workbook object to the frontend */
        return XLSX.read(bstr, {type:'binary'});
            Contacts.insert({ "spreadsheet": bstr });
    },
});
```

but I cannot import the data to collection.

Comment: Eh...you should place `return` in the end of the function, right?

Comment: The XLSX format is not JSON, it's Binary. As such, as long as the content is under 16MB then just insert it as a regular field value. i.e `Contact.insert({ "spreadsheet": bstr })`. But do that without the "loop". Just read the binary into the variable and insert it. Nothing else required. If larger than 16MB then [see GridFS](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/gridfs/) to store over multiple documents as binary. But simply try including as a regular property first. MongoDB was built with that in mind.

Comment: I have got the answer from this thread: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45829409/how-can-i-insert-document-on-server-side-for-meteor-mongodb](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45829409/how-can-i-insert-document-on-server-side-for-meteor-mongodb)